# Custom post type not using it's own single-postname.php

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

I have a custom post type (that I'm using on a template page), the custom post type is called 'headerhome'. When I post say a gallery there I'm trying to get it to redirect to 'single-headerhome.php', yet it always just goes to 'single.php'.

The name of the custom post type itself is arbitrary, the name of the templage page it's on is 'front-page.php'.

I'm really confused, I'm not the best at WP yet so when something simple like this doesn't work I have no idea how to fix it, even after pouring over the codex for an hour.

```
// Add new post type for homepage
add_action('init', 'frontpage_top_init');
function frontpage_top_init() 
{
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Homepage'),
        'singular_label' => __('Homepage'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','editor'),
        'has_archive' => true
    ); 
    register_post_type('headerhome',$args);

}
```

Here's my code on the front-page.php

EDIT:-

```
<?php 
/*
    Template Name: frontpage
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content">
<div class="head-home">
      <?php
$portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'headerhome',
        'showposts' => 1
        ) );
?>
      <?php while ($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post(); ?>

       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
      <?php the_content(); ?>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div class="embed-container">
      <?php the_field('showreel'); ?>

  </div> <!-- end div embed-container -->   

    </div> <!-- end div head-home -->               

    <div class="gallerydescription">
        <?php the_field ('gallery-description'); ?>
    </div> <!-- end div gallerydescription -->  

<?php the_field('image-1'); ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>

</div> <!-- end div main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

No matter what I try, it always uses single.php and not single-headerhome.php.
If my understand of wordpress is correct, and it's probably not - shouldn't creating the template file single-headerhome.php automatically make wordpress use that for this post type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you flushed your permalinks?

If not, visit your permalinks page in your dashboard, then, refresh the page you are trying to view.

Let us know if that helps.

#### Edit:

Upon re-reading your question, actually, no - just because you create a single-post_type.php file does not mean WordPress will use that file with regards to your front-page.php template file.

Your front-page.php file is what is rendering your post. This is your issue.

If you want your single-post_type.php file to render the display of your post type within front-page.php then you can do the following;

```
<?php
$portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'headerhome',
'showposts' => 1
));
?>

<?php while ($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('single-post_type.php'); ?>
   
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

But obviously make sure that single-post_type.php does not contain a loop/query within itself for if it does then you should remove the outer while/endwhile statements contained within front-page.php

Comment: Yeah I've flushed my permalinks.

Well no, I want front-page.php to render my post, I just want single-headerhome.php to be used when a gallery image or something is clicked on.
Currently it uses the single.php.

Or maybe I've misunderstood you, I'm sort of new to wordpress!

Comment: Ok so it seems to be a little unclear here. `front-page.php` will handle what you see on the front page, when you click through to a single post type link, the `single-post_type.php` will come into effect. I'm stating the obvious I know, but I'm trying to understand the relevance of your `front-page.php` in this issue when you seem to be talking about being on a single page (after someone has clicked a link). i.e. `domain.com/my-post-type-permalink` instead of `domain.com`

Comment: Well the fact I mentioned front-page.php was just incidental so people knew I was using a template page for the custom post type.

www.scottomahony.co.uk is the site.
It's just a simple site I'm making for a friend.

However single-post_type.php is NOT working, that's the problem.
It's always using single.php when I click through on images etc.
That's what I'd like to fix, i'd like it to use single-post_type.php, or single-headerhome.php as it's called.

Comment: What is the "portfolio" parameter in your permalink represent /post_type/portfolio/%postname% ? Is that a category? Taxonomy?

Comment: Nope, it's just named after the name of the front page.

Comment: Upon further inspection I can see that you are linking to the attachment page for the image, not the individual post page. Therefore WP is looking for `attachment.php` and because it does not find it, WP then reverts to `single.php`. You are not trying to view a single-post_type.php page. That's the issue. Your front-page.php file does not make sense either. Its like its incomplete because it doesn't show me how you are linking to your custom post type files. Something is a miss here... Please provide the full script that is controlling your front page, or your index.php file.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code from front-page.php in it's entirity.

Comment: You're not using `front-page.php` at all. You're using a *custom page template* named `homepage.php`. Those are two *very different* things. As for why you're linking to the *attachment* template rather than to the *single post* template: it looks like that's because you're outputting `the_content()` (which displays the image linked to the attachment itself), but do not display `the_permalink()` (which would link to the post). **Try adding `the_permalink()` to the loop output.**

Comment: The issue here is that you are querying your custom post type which contains 1 post with an embedded gallery of image-attachments. The images themselves are linking to the individual attachment pages. You can see this when you go into the custom post type POST edit screen and click on the media library icon, then the GALLERY tab. You will see 3 buttons that allow you to link directly tot he image (FILE), to the attachment page (CURRENTLY selected) or nothing at all. That's your problem. When you click on the image, you are seeing single.php because WP is looking for attachment.php first!

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it now.
Thanks chip and user~, I feel like a real idiot now, it was so simple.
I didn't realise gallery images link to attachment first and not single-post_name.php.
Would I be able to have them link to like attachment-post_name.php or is that only for permalinks?

Comment: You can remove the links from the images within the media library gallery tab in the custom post type edit screen then you can wrap your output (in template file with) `<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="...etc"/></a>` where the <img> tag references whatever you are using to output your images. If its `the_content` you could either wrap that. Or if its your custom field you can wrap that instead. I didn't notice the actual title on your site even though its in the template (?) otherwise that too could be wrapped with a permalink to the post.

Comment: Using attachment.php with the exact same code as single.php (minus the sidebar) seems not to output the image at all... this is so confusing.